# Process a form with javascript and use it in pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Theres a form on a website I'm trying to make and I was wondering if there was a way to click the submit button for the form and then have a pop up use that information

sorry for the newb question, code is kind of like this:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="submitform()" type="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
<a>
<input type = "submit" value = "Submit"
</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
    username = document.getElementsByName("username")
    window.alert("hi:" username)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there's a few issues with your code, but you're close.

- Submit buttons shouldn't be inside of `<a>` tags. You're also missing the closing carrot here.
- You're using `type`, but I'm guessing you meant `method`.
- In your JavaScript, you're getting an array of elements with `getElementsByName` and never getting the value.

Put that all together, and:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="submitform()" method="POST">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script>
function submitform()
{
    username = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value
    window.alert("hi:" username)
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<form name="myform" onsubmit="submitform(this) return false;" type="POST">
```

then in your function:

```
function submitform(form)
{
    username = document.getElementsByName("username")
    window.alert("hi:" username)
}
```

Then use the form object your passing in.

```
if ($(form).valid())
{
    var fields = $(form).serializeArray();

    $(fields).each(function ()
    {
      if (this.name !== undefined)
      {
          var propertyName = this.name;
          var propertyValue = this.value;

         //Do something
       }
    });
}
```